# FatalThrowableError al usar DatabaseSeeder, para poblar

Tags: laravel, seeders

estoy haciendo una prueba, para poblar la bd, usando DatabaseSeeder. Tengo un archivo VehiculosSeeder individual, un modelo Vehiculo, vinculado a la tabla vehiculos, y cuando intento ejecutar desde consola php artisan db:seed, obtengo esto:

```
    Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'Model'      not found

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\logismart\database\seeds\DatabaseSeeder.php:14
    10|      * @return void
    11|      */
    12|     public function run()
    13|     {
  > 14|        Model::unguard();
    15|
    16|            $this->call(VehiculosSeeder::class);  // ejemplo ejecucion seeder
    17|                                                 //$this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    18|        Model::reguard();

  Exception trace:

  1   DatabaseSeeder::run()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\logismart\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:29

  2   call_user_func_array([])
      C:\xampp\htdocs\logismart\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:29.
```

Mi modelo vehiculo esta asi:

```
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Vehiculo;

class Vehiculo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'vehiculos';
    protected $fillable = array ['id', 'matricula', 'marca', 'capacidadCarga', 'añoFabricacion', 'color'];


    public function ordenes
        {   
            return $this->hasOne('ordenesCargas');

        }
}
```

Mi seeder individual VehiculosSeeder esta asi:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class VehiculosSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
         Vehiculo::create([
             'id'    =>    001,
             'matricula'   =>    09890,
             'marca'   =>    Volkswagen,
             'capacidadCarga'   =>    20,
             'añoFabricacion'   =>    2001,
             'color'   =>    blanco,

         ])   //
    }
}
```

DatabaseSeeder queda asi:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
       Model::unguard(); 

           $this->call(VehiculosSeeder::class);  // ejemplo ejecucion seeder
                                                //$this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
       Model::reguard();     
    }
}
```

¿Pueden indicarme que estoy haciendo mal?. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu campo id es autoincrement no debes ni siquiera incluirlo en tu seeder y el otro detalle es que debes pasar los valores de tu columna con el tipo de datos que es.

```
  Vehiculo::create([
         'matricula'   =>    '09890',
         'marca'   =>    'Volkswagen',
         'capacidadCarga'   =>    20,
         'añoFabricacion'   =>    2001,
         'color'   =>    'blanco',

     ]);
```

Imagino que el campo matricula es un string porque comienza por 0 vaya seria un poco ortodoxo guardar un entero con un 0 delante, no tendria sentido, de todas formas te puedes llevar la idea.

Y por último emplear el using para que no de error al usar la clase **Model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

Comment: Hola @Dariel Ramos Diaz de Villegas, he corregido lo que me indicas, ahora me tira otro error pero por lo menos ese lo he resuelto, sigo revisando, gracias

Comment: Crea otra pregunta y asi podre ayudarte saludos